# Add a 'data-toggle' attribute to a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying create a bootstrap tooltip in a button in javascript.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
 <input type="image" src="~/images/icon_trash_red.png" class="m-l-20" onclick="RemoveItem(this)" height="20"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Remover aluno" />
```

This is what I have so far:

```
    button = document.createElement("Input");
    button.src = "/images/icon_trash_red.png";
    button.width = '20';
    button.type = 'image';
    button.onclick = function () {
       RemoveItem(this);
    };
    button.style.marginLeft = '70px';
    button.title = "Remover aluno";
    button.setAttribute("data-toggle", "tooltip");
```

The 'setAttribute' seems to be working fine, because if I change to something like this: `button.setAttribute("height", "50px");` it works.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will add the attribute to the element but you need to initialize the tooltip.

```
// initialize tooltip for all elements which has the data-toggle attribute
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()

// or initialize just for the button
$(button).tooltip()
```

**Note :** The code should be after adding the attribute to the element.

Comment: @Perozzo so what is your question then when the attribute gets added?

Comment: Also, make sure you've added the element to the page first before calling tooltip()

Comment: @Perozzo: I fyou're doing that **before** adding the attribute to the button, it won't pick up that button. Once you add the attribute, you need to call `$(button).tooltip()` to initialize tooltips for that button, since it didn't previously have the attribute. (Don't use Pranav's first example, if you've already done it, no need to re-initialize the others.)

Comment: Thank you so much @PranavCBalan @T.J.Crowder @Dave. I was calling `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` just once and before the button's creation. Just added `$(button).tooltip();` and it worked like a charm!